# Opening a .csv file using only ";" as a separator

Tags: excel, csv, separator, vba

I am opening a .csv file from a http link using the `Workbooks.Open Filename:=` _, and it gets all bugged because Excel interprets commas as column separators instead of ";" which is used by the table.

How could I make the vba code to interpret comma as a decimal separator, like 0,5 = 5/10 and the ";" sign as a column separator when I open this file?

Comment: the problem is just the separator, the rest will take care of itself, excel under import has flexible parameters for importing files, how are you opening into excel?

Comment: I'm using     `Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
        "http://XXX/FIlename.csv", Delimiter:=";"` to open it, but the delimiter code does not help much

Answer (score 0):

I checked, if you go to data menu in excel and select to import text file, follow wizard and you can choose semicolon for delimiter

Comment: try this instead, I found in another post. sep=; for the delimiter portion

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:
`Workbooks.OpenText filename:=http://XXX/FIlename.csv, _
    DataType:=xlDelimited, Semicolon:=True`

Instead of this:
`Workbooks.Open Filename:= _ "http://XXX/FIlename.csv", Delimiter:=";"`